# For text mining in R, how do I combine DocumentTermMatrix with original Data Frame?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

What I am looking to do is create code that will allow me to classify tweets. So in the example below I would want to take tweets talking about a credit card and determine if they are related to the issue of travel.

Here is the initial dataset:

```
id<- c(123,124,125,126,127) 
text<- c("Since I love to travel, this is what I rely on every time.", 
        "I got this card for the no international transaction fee", 
        "I got this card mainly for the flight perks",
        "Very good card, easy application process",
        "The customer service is outstanding!") 
travel_cat<- c(1,0,1,0,0) 
df_all<- data.frame(id,text,travel)
```

Output 1:

```
id  text                                                        travel_cat
123 Since I love to travel, this is what I rely on every time.  1
124 I got this card for the no international transaction fee    0
125 I got this card mainly for the flight perks                 1
126 Very good card, easy application process                    0
127 The customer service is outstanding!                        0
```

I am then creating a data frame with only the text field and then doing the text analytics:

```
myvars<- c("text")
df<- df_all[myvars]

library(tm)
corpus<- Corpus(DataframeSource(df))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
dtm<- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus))
```

Output 2 (dtm):

```
Docs    application card    customer    easy    every ... etc.
1       0           0       0           1       0
2       0           1       0           0       1
3       0           1       0           0       0
4       1           1       0           0       0
5       0           0       1           0       0
```

How do I then tie this back to the original data so that it contains the fields from the original dataset and the matrix (Output 1 + Output 2):
    id,text,travel_cat + application,card,customer,easy,every...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try a `cbind()`

```
allcombined <- cbind(dtm,df_all)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes.. wow that was a much more simple solution that what I thought it would be. Thanks!